# How to find the least utility in a banana harvest?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, optimization, economics

> A certain farm in Suwon produces a certain amount of bananas. This is
> given by the expresion from below:
>
> $$Q(x)=12 \sec ^2 x +48\tan x +36$$
>
> This represents hundreds of US dollars.
>
> Assuming $x$ is given by an acute angle, and we know that the utility
> of such farm is an integer number of US dollars. Find the least
> utility of such farm.

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{4801 usd}\\
2.&\textrm{4851 usd}\\
3.&\textrm{4849 usd}\\
4.&\textrm{4999 usd}\\
\end{array}$

What I did in my attempt to find the least was to complete the square and use this fact:

$(a)^2\geq 0$

And: $1+\tan^2 \omega = \sec^2 \omega$

Then replacing these in the aforementioned utility function I'm getting:

$Q(x)=12 \sec ^2 x +48\tan x +36$

$Q(x)=12(1+\tan^2 x)+48\tan x +36$

$Q(x)=12+12\tan ^2x +48\tan x +36$

$Q(x)=\left(\sqrt{12}\tan x +\frac{24}{\sqrt{12}}\right)^2$

Then this becomes into:

$\left(\sqrt{12}\tan x +\frac{24}{\sqrt{12}}\right)^2 \geq 0$

Then it mentions that $x$ is an acute angle therefore:

$0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$

Then I assumed that:

$\tan 0 < \tan x <\tan\frac{\pi}{2}$

$0< \tan x < \infty$

Then I completed the interval as it was given by the mentioned square:

$0 < \sqrt{12}\tan x < \infty$

$\frac{24}{\sqrt{12}} < \sqrt{12}\tan x + \frac{24}{\sqrt{12}} < \infty$

$48 < \left(\sqrt{12}\tan x + \frac{24}{\sqrt{12}}\right)^2 < \infty$

Since the function represents **hundreds of US dollars** then I assumed I had to multiply by $100$ the earlier inequation to obtain the least profit or utility.

$4800 < \left(\sqrt{12}\tan x + \frac{24}{\sqrt{12}}\right)^2 < \infty$

Since it mentions that the **least profit or utility** is **integer** then I assumed that this would be $4801$ which is the next number or the local minima. But is this a right assumption?

This result appears in one of the alternatives. But I'm not sure if my rationale is correct.

The reason of this is that I had to multiply for $100$ to one side of the inequality, not the other terms, in other words the part which is in the center and the infinity. For obvious reasons it doesn't really matter much to multiply to infinity because it will remain the same, but for the part which is the function in the center, this confuses me.

So all and all is my method correct?. Can someone explain this me better?. The thing is I'm looking for a method which would refrain from using derivatives and approach this using precalculus tools.

Therefore, can someone help me?. Please I require **step by step** explanation because I often get a little bit tangled with equations and concepts.

Comment: **Your method is correct.** You could factor out $12$ initially to get a nicer look. $12(\tan^2x + 4\tan x + 4) = 12(\tan x+2)^2$. $\tan x +2 $ has a  value  $>2$ in the specified range and $12(2^2) = 48$

Comment: You did essentially everything right! (all in all, I think this is correct) The only minor gap is (which you yourself note) is asking whether you can immediately take the first integer after 4800, and the answer is yes. That is because tan x is not only between 0 and infinity, but also takes every value in between for x acute, so there is some x such that that square is indeed equal to 4801. (I am not leaving this as an answer since you want a better explanation than the one you gave and I don't think I can provide one?)

Comment: @Ak Thanks for the input. So, should it be worthy of an upvote, please?. By the way, I did not factor $12$ initially because I was not sure how to use it properly. I think had I used your approach it would had simplified the equations. It confuses me a bit, but you are using $\tan x +2 =2$ to replace it in the equation so is $12(2)^2$, but why not $3$, if the boundary is open? I mean why you took $2$?.

Comment: @Ak Isn't $0<\tan x < \infty$ or in the specified range is $0\leq \tan x < \infty$? Maybe can you explain this part to me?. I'd appreciate if you could do that.

Comment: $x$ lies in the range $(0,\frac\pi2)$.  Let's take (arbitrarily) $x = 0.5^\circ \approx 0.0087 $ radian and for this small $x$, $\tan x \approx x = 0.0087$. Here $2+\tan x \approx 2.0087$ is much nearer to $2$ than $3$ and it's square is $ \approx 4.035$.   

You can get many such angles such that $2+\tan x$ is much closer to $2$ than $3$